# Log4xx as Cocoa framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, log4cxx

We're currently using log4xx on OS X as `.dylib` and having frequent runtime problems with applications failing to load the library, wrong paths, multiple libraries in each framework they're used in.

Is there an existing project using *log4xx* as an [OS X framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html)?

The currrent Xcode projects in log4xx just build dylibs so wondering if there's any particular reason or what would break if using log4xx as a framework on OS X?

Answer (score 2):

Most the time when I want to use a third-party framework, instead of hassling with the framework itself I just drop the actual source files into my Xcode project and compile and link them directly. It’s amazing how many things will work without modification this way.

Comment: True, that's what we do for most other files as well - but build times are getting pretty mean even for our medium sized apps. And we're not even close to DL in terms of complexity (I suppose) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, the log4xx project has moved to Apache and they've just kicked off development of a new release after a couple of quiet years:

http://incubator.apache.org/projects/log4cxx2.html

Bugs and suggestions - such as better OS X integration - can be logged here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/issue-tracking.html

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - after having multiple issues converting the log4cxx into a framework (it's a .dylib with a JAM makefile in the current distribution) I've scrapped the approach and went straight to **Boost.Log**..